# What API can be used to read OAB Files?

Tags: c#

I have OAB file with me.Now i want to programatically read it's content using c#.
Can anyone suggest me some APIs which can be used to read OAB files.
And related information of them.

**Note: Not reading OAB file form Outlook or Exchange Server** 
(I don't want to  read OAB from Exchange or Outlook.)

Explanation:

I am manually copying this file from exchange server on my PC.And now i want to read this OAB (offline Address Book).
I don't want my application to read OAB files from Exchange or Outlook.
I want my application to just allow user to browse OAB file saved on his machine and now read this file.

Hope now it is clear  :(

Comment: What are OAB files that are not from Outlook or Exchange? Where _are_ they from?

Comment: I made Changes in question.Hope now it is clear.

Comment: It's not clear.

What application is generating these OAB files? Where are they coming from.

Comment: Is that the OAuthBase reference???

Comment: I made changes again in my post.Hope now i am able to explain :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any API doing this, but you can write your own interface using the Microsoft [specification for OAB files](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/D/D/5DD33FDF-91F5-496D-9884-0A0B0EE698BB/%5BMS-OXOAB%5D.pdf).